# iPhone - CGPoint distance in pixels and screen resolution

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, screen, resolution, cgpoint

I have this code into the `- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context` method (into a MKOverlayView subclass) to prevent drawing segments that are less than 10 pixels long on a map overlay :

```
            CGPoint origin = [self pointForMapPoint:poly.points[0]];
            CGPoint lastPoint = origin;

            CGContextMoveToPoint(context, origin.x, origin.y);

            for (int i=1; i<poly.pointCount; i++) {
                CGPoint point = [self pointForMapPoint:poly.points[i]];

                CGFloat xDist = (point.x - lastPoint.x);
                CGFloat yDist = (point.y - lastPoint.y);
                CGFloat distance = sqrt((xDist * xDist) + (yDist * yDist)) * zoomScale;

                if (distance >= 10.0) {
                    lastPoint = point;
                    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
                }
            }
```

will the test >= 10.0 will take care about the screen resolution, or may I introduce some `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale` parameter ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that test >= 10.0 does not take into account the screen resolution. Apple does most of their drawing arithmetic using "points" instead of pixels- that way code does not have to change for a retina display compared to a normal display.

If you want to draw something just 10.0 pixels wide, you will need to take into account the screen resolution; however, if you do this you'll have to write the method to support both retina display and normal display.

Comment: It's in the `- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context` method (MKOverlayView subclass). What do you think I should do ?

Comment: The test will ignore the screen resolution, so you need to ask if you're trying not to draw something 10 pixels wide or something 10 points wide. I would go with points (because it transitions between devices better) and then you don't have to change your current code.

Comment: I don't want to ignore it, I want line in pixels size, not point. should I insert .scale property ?

Comment: Yes, then I think you should put in the .scale property. Definitely test it out to make sure that it is working, but I think that will work.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how the graphics context is configured. If this is in `UIView` drawing code, the view's scale factor (which is set automatically) will take care of this, if you're drawing into a bitmap context, you have to do it manually.

Comment: It's in the `- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)context` method (MKOverlayView subclass). May I do something like >= 10.0 / self.view.scale ?

Comment: There's nothing else mentioned in the docs, so I'd assume that the scale factor is already set in the context. Btw, this method runs on a background thread, so you have to be a bit careful.

Comment: being careful about what ? What is the relation between the scale and the fact it's a background thread ?